# PHP + MySQL "INSERT INTO" error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

I have this sql string:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO foto (id, nome, check)
            VALUES ('', '" . md5($file) . '.' .$Type. "', '" . md5($file2) . '.' .$Type2. "')";
```

but it returns this error:

```
INSERT INTO foto (nome, check) VALUES ('57f030f902b9fbd6907d1af52ec2a1ba.jpg', '8c96b1254a72dbd080a9b79a9a224865.jpg')
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'check) VALUES ('57f030f902b9fbd6907d1af52ec2a1ba.jpg', '8c96b1254a72dbd080a9' at line 1
```

'

```
md5($file) + $Type = 57f030f902b9fbd6907d1af52ec2a1ba.jpg
md5($file2) + $Type2 = 8c96b1254a72dbd080a9b79a9a224865.jpg
```

What's the problem? How can I solve it?

Comment: You really should be using SQL placeholders like `?` or `:nome` for this, because the way you're composing this query string seems completely reckless. Are any of those values even [properly escaped](http://bobby-tablesl.com/php)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`check` is a MySQL reserved word

- **http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html**

which requires it to be wrapped in backticks, or rename it to `checks` for example in your table.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO foto (id, nome, `check`)
```

if you want to rename it, then just do

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO foto (id, nome, checks)
```

which won't throw an error; the option is yours.

---

Notice where the error starts and points to:

```
>...MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'check
                                                          ^ starts there
```

---

Plus, once you've fixed that, your code would still be open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/).
Use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

Comment: Thank you. "check" was the problem. I know that is an unsafe query but it is inside a secure and private area of the website in which only one person can enter. I will, however, once finished the entire code, make sure this area too. Thank you very much.